# Which song plays when Lelouch tells to the world he's the emperor of Britannia in ep 25 of R2?

Tags: music, code-geass

What is the OST played at 11:35 in the ep 25 of R2 of Code Geass?

Answer (score 1):

Fittingly called "All Hail Britannia"
[Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ykpDQhWlrBQ)

Answer (score 1):

You mean the music during his "Attention, entire world" speech?
That's the OST "The Master".
Unfortunately, it seems all original versions of it on youtube have been taken down, but luckily I managed to find it somewhere else.
https://soundcloud.com/lord-snowman/code-geass-lelouch-of-the-rebellion-r2-ost-21-the-master
Enjoy!